# Is there something wrong with this code in javas

Tags: java.util.scanner

int number=new Scanner(System.in);

if(number%2==0){
System.out.println("the number entered is even");

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not obtain a value with the keyboard with that statement.
"new Scanner(System.in)" is the constructor for an object of type Scanner that reads from keyboard, but first you create the Scanner object (which is stored in a reference of type Scanner), and then you use methods of that class that reads values from keyboard.

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in)
```

the above creates a Scanner object and stores a reference to it in a variable named "keyboard". Now, [methods in the Scanner class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html) will return the values introduced by keyboard depending on the type, in this case

```
int number = keyboard.nextInt()
```

The second part is ok